# Keras: How to equalize the dimensions of 2 layers for Concatenation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation

My goal is to concatenate two layers of different dimensions as well as different numbers of filters. As for concatenation operation, the dimensions of both layers should be the same. Which operation is recommended to set the dimensions?

Code:

```
x1 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
x1 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x1)
x1 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, trainable=True) (x1)

x2 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x2)
x2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, trainable=True) (x2)
c1 = crop_and_concat(x1,x2)
```

The error message I got is:

> ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes
> except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 75, 75, 16),
> (None, 37, 37, 32)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, the reason why you cannot concatenate is of course the height and width of the feature maps(thanks for pointing that out in the comment section, I misunderstood you question at first).

The reason why you cannot concatenate is in this line of code:

```
x2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x2)
```

1. If you remove this `AveragePooling2D()` then the dimension is not
   reduced and you can concatenate on `axis=3` (or `-1` for that
   matter). `37` comes from integer division by `2` (both on height and
   width) ==> `75 // 2 = 37.`
2. There is another trick that you could do. You could use `Upsampling2D((2,2))` to arrive back from `(37,37)` to `(74,74)`. However this is not enough as, due to the remainder of an integer division by 2 from an odd number, we still need to process the width and height to arrive to `(75,75)` from `(74,74)`. You can solve this by using a `ZeroPadding2D` layer, such as `ZeroPadding2D((1,0),(0,0))`

Another thing to consider(providing the same dimensions of the filters) is for number of filters reduction(read this if you are also interested in this aspect):

You can use 1x1 Convolution for reducing the dimension of the filters.

Here is an example:

```
# example of a 1x1 filter for dimensionality reduction
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation='relu'))
# summarize model
model.summary()
```

This is the output of the `model.summary()`

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 512)     14336
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 256, 256, 64)      32832
=================================================================
Total params: 47,168
Trainable params: 47,168
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The example is taken from here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-1x1-convolutions-to-reduce-the-complexity-of-convolutional-neural-networks/. I wrote the code since the link may break in the future but the code is visible and can be left as it is.

Of course, the example is in the `Sequential()` format but the gist is this line of code(which you have to slightly modify to your purpose):

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation='relu'))
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, concatenation doesn't need the same number of filters. Feature size dimension matters. How I can use to reduce the size (dimension) of feature size.

Comment: Yews, sorry, for some reason I misunderstood your problem. Let me delete/modify this one and come with a good answer once I figure it out.

Comment: So the problem in your case is then that 75 75 cannot be concatenated with 37 37

Comment: Please check the updated answer, and thank you for providing that info, I misinterpreted the question in the first read.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is satisfactory. Let's see if there is any other idea for dimensions matching.

Comment: There is another trick you could do: You could use UpSampling2D and then ZeroPadding2D() . The Upsampling2D() will lead us to the dimension of 74,74, but we need 75,75 since we cannot concatenate otherwise. This is where ZeroPadding2D falls into place, just pad with 0 a row/column on entire matrix

Comment: Updated the answer with the second solution.

Comment: @John, since you accepted my answer, would you be so kind as to also upvote it? It helps me and the others. Thank you